# 2.8 or 2.81 for beginner

Tags: compatibility

I wanna try to switch from Max to Blender and after the release of 2.81 I have the following question - Is it better to use 2.8 or 2.81 for someone who has never used Blender but at the same time is not new in 3d. The reason I ask is that I want to try some cool plugins such as mira, mesh machine, hardops, boxcutter, etc... In Max when you download a new version you have to wait for the new versions of plugins as some of them do not have forward compatibility and may work pretty buggy in the new release. So, have Blender plugins been already updated for the new version or do they have forward compatibility with new version. (and if they need an update how long does it usually take, I still have some time to learn the UI and the basics)

Comment: It varies for each *addon*, you will have to check the addons' documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no harm in trying out 2.81 and exploring Blender.
If you are new to Blender, go to page 4 for the playlists of tutorials, which I consider the BEST for absolute beginners. 
[Blender Tutorials scrapbook](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13UpIjJEE7Oa7x5BiMsjXGW5CGOTDF03-SocRYi4Babs/mobilepresent?slide=id.g646f12fe70d42be6_0)

Some addons or plugins get regularly updated. I have two versions of Blender on my PC: 2.79 and 2.8. I just changed the name of folder containing 2.79b files, before downloading 2.8, as I wanted to keep 2.79b because of old addons and Blend files.

Comment: Thanks, it is a nice solution that I didn't even consider. Blender is very slim so multiple version installed on one computer is not problem

Comment: A directory here. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1TyUpu4zylhDkEAKpepI9P6HkvtmonJG7zEBLsHgWCjI/mobilepresent?slide=id.g30cdd00c4b1ec5f9_0.  Inside, I have over 25 scrapbooks on Blender. They are all roughs, study purpose only.